# Passing user ID in body or in token

Tags: rest, authorization, jwt, api-design

I'm building a REST API. The API runs a JWT authentication system.

Obviously this means that paths that are secure need a valid JWT token to be passed along with the request in the Authorization Header. Inside each jwt token I have:

```
    sub: 1 //_id
```

Where sub is the Id of the currently authenticated user.

My question is, when I pass this token, is there a need to pass the user id in the request body also? For instance, I have a create premises method. This requires a post body to contain a name and description like so:

```
    {
        name: "Test Premises",
        description: "Lorem Ipsum"
    }
```

In this case, the API would have to find the user to associate the new premises by verifying the token passed is valid, then unencoding it and retrieving the sub field.

Is this method ok?

are there any drawbacks?

should I be passing Id's in the body aswell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is this method ok

Yes, that's the point of the authentication token.

> should I be passing Id's in the body aswell?

You have a *really* big security hole if you allow the user ID to be sent from the client e.g. another authenticated user could create premises on behalf of another user if they knew (or spoofed) their ID.

Comment: Changing the user ID would invalidate the token

Comment: @user2976358 what has changing ID got to do with anything?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your answer. But you said if an authenticated user spoofed another users ID they could create a premises on their behalf. If the user were to edit their token to change the id it would invalidate it.

Comment: @mwild I'm referring to this point "*should I be passing Id's in the body aswell*". If you use the ID from the body and not the one in the auth token then this is exploitable - golden rule, never trust the client.

Comment: Ah that's a fair point. Although I don't think your original answer makes it entirely clear you are talking about the id being passed in the body. Thanks any how.

Comment: @James please help me understand - which scenario is more secure according to you ?

scenario 1 :  client passes token & server validates token, fetches users and carries on..

scenario 2: client passes token & userId to server.  Server validates token + it checks that this token belongs to this userId only. If  (userId, token) combination is incorrect, it will revoke this token , as it's a possibility of a malicious client..